# Notepad++ Regex, Get everything between a string and a dynamic number followed by string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to convert this:

```
<g_n><![CDATA[zxcvzxcv, zx123vz123xc13vv150 , xxxx GSD 3363200 3Vo1asdf23l 4338D asdf]]></g_n>
```

to:

```
<g_n><![CDATA[xxxx GSD 3363200 3Vo1asdf23l 4338D asdf]]></g_n>
```

where xxxx can be any number between 1 and 9999

Here is my regex so far, I'm very close:

```
(?<=<g_n\><!\[CDATA\[).*(?<=[0-9] GSD)
```

I don't know how to make my regex find any number before GSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this will works for any expression holding `CDATA\[` whats after last colon contains one or more digits together

```
   (.*)(CDATA\[)(.*)(,\s)([0-9]+)(.*)
   \1\2\5\6\7
```

Your number is hidden under `\5` so give it a try and in replace put only `\5` an see what happens (generally is good to use groups in parenthesis for fast extraction needed elements)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following pattern

```
<g_n><!\[CDATA\[\d{1,4} GSD(.|\s)*\]\]></g_n>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Providing you're using notepad++ 6.3.3 (there were problems with notepad 5.x.x with regex searches).

Your desired output looks like it's simply subtracting the first two chunks of comma separated data from your input string. You can use this to find and remove the values from your input string

Regex: `\b[a-z]{8}\b,\s\b[a-z0-9]{19}\b\s,\s\b`
Replace with: `empty field`

If you want to simply capture other text so that you can validate it is exactly what you're looking to retain then you could use this regex

Regex: `(<g_n><!\[CDATA\[).*?,\s?(\d{1,4}\sGSD\s.*?<\/g_n>)` 
Replace with `$1$2`

## Example

**First Option**:

In this example I'm simply marking the text to show that it actually locates the string as expected

[image]

This example shows how I've popluated the search/replace dialog box
[image]

**Second Option**:

The regex fills past the field width in the form

Regex: `(<g_n><!\[CDATA\[).*?,\s?(\d{1,4}\sGSD\s.*?<\/g_n>)`

[image]